Hide the Authorization Header in PHP-FPM
I need to make Apache's mod_auth_basic opaque to PHP-FPM so that I can run scripts that get confused by Authorization headers.  I've tried a variety of CGI and Header directives and so far am unable to hide the headers from PHP.
Specifically, with AuthType Basic the PHP-FPM environment is always including these values:
$_SERVER['AUTH_TYPE']
$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']
$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']

I'm using Apache 2.4 and PHP8.3-FPM in Ubuntu 20.04.6.
The last resort would be adding a proxy server, but I'm hoping for a simpler solution.

After hours of digging through Apache docs, I found this one:
ProxyFCGISetEnvIf Directive
And here's what worked for me to make AuthType Basic completely opaque:
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    ProxyFCGISetEnvIf true !AUTH_TYPE
    ProxyFCGISetEnvIf true !HTTP_AUTHORIZATION
    ProxyFCGISetEnvIf true !REMOTE_USER
</FilesMatch>


BTW, you are allowed to tick your own answers after a day.
